# Problema de lógica no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estou pedindo para imprimir apenas o nome e notas. Porem ele está duplicando na hora de imprimir. Ou seja... Se eu digitei João, 1,2,3,4; Pedro,3,4,5,6.  Na hora de imprimir, ele imprime duas vezes a mesma coisa.

```js
//criar sala de aula com 4 alunos que possuem 4 notas e depois calcular a média de cada aluno.
//Sem objeto

var sala = [];
var aluno = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      aluno.push(prompt("Digite o nome"));
    } else {
      aluno.push(prompt("Digite a nota"));
    }

  }
  sala.push(aluno);
}
console.info(sala.length);
for (var i = 0; i < sala.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < sala[i].length; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      console.log(sala[i][j]);
    } else {
      //console.log(parseFloat(sala[i][j]));
      console.log(sala[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Como assim? Podes me explicar o funcionamento? =/

Comment: Então comecei a estudar JavaScript agora, daí me perco com o que pode ou não. Eu queria com Array mesmo, depois que farei com Objeto.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver essa questão?

Comment: Sim. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Por favor aceite uma das respostas caso elas tenham lhe ajudado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No enunciado, ele pede para criar *uma* sala, e *quatro* alunos, e estes com *quatro notas*. Só que, ao criar suas variáveis, você cria *um aluno só*:

```
var sala = [];
var aluno = []; // <- isso deveria representar apenas 1 aluno
```

> Isso, em si, não representa um problema, você poderia guardar mais alunos neste mesmo `array`, mas aí você não precisaria do `array` `sala`. Veja onde está o problema:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            aluno.push(prompt("Digite o nome")); // aluno recebe 4 nomes
        } else {
            aluno.push(prompt("Digite a nota")); // e 16 notas
        }
    }
    sala.push(aluno); // o mesmo aluno é passado para sala, 4 vezes
}
```

> **Ou seja:**
> `sala[0]`, `sala[1]`, `sala[2]` e `sala[3]` terão referência para **exatamente** o mesmo objeto. Para um exemplo "visual" do que está ocorrendo, dê uma olhada neste [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orLog2nw/).

Isso acontece porque em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), arrays são objetos, e portanto são passados como **referência** para funções e não como cópia do valor como é o caso de primitivos.

A solução do @joserogerio84 funciona, porque ele não está somente "zerando" o array a cada iteração, ele está *criando um novo*.

### Veja um exemplo funcionando abaixo:

```js
/*
*  criar sala de aula com 4 alunos que possuem 4 notas
*  e depois calcular a média de cada aluno.
*  Sem objeto
*/

    let sala = [];
    let aluno = [];
    let t = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                aluno.push(prompt("Digite o nome"));
            } else {
                aluno.push(prompt("Digite a nota"));
            }
        }
        sala.push(aluno); // mandamos a referencia desse aluno para sala
        aluno = []; // isso cria um novo array com o mesmo nome
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < sala.length; i++) {
        let linha = t.insertRow(t.rows.length);
        for (let j = 0; j < sala[i].length; j++) {
          saida(linha, j, sala[i][j]);   
        }
    }
    
function saida(linha, numero, texto) {
    linha.insertCell(numero).appendChild(document.createTextNode(texto));
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nota</th>
  <th>Nota</th>
  <th>Nota</th>
  <th>Nota</th>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou somente zerar o array de alunos no inicio do for:

```
//criar sala de aula com 4 alunos que possuem 4 notas e depois calcular a média de cada aluno.
//Sem objeto

var sala = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var aluno = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      aluno.push(prompt("Digite o nome"));
    } else {
      aluno.push(prompt("Digite a nota"));
    }

  }
  sala.push(aluno);
}
console.info(sala.length);
for (var i = 0; i < sala.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < sala[i].length; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      console.log(sala[i][j]);
    } else {
      //console.log(parseFloat(sala[i][j]));
      console.log(sala[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Podes me explicar melhor? Porque em Java eu criava a maioria das variaveis fora mesmo. E não entendi o motivo de ter de colocar dentro do for =(

Comment: Se você não inicializar dentro do for, o array de alunos só vai crescendo. Inicializando o array de alunos dentro do loop você cria um novo array a cada iteração e ao final empilha o mesmo no array de salas.

Comment: No caso poderia manter fora, mas reiniciá-lo após fazer o `sala.push`; algo como: `alunos = []`. Dica: para versões mais novas do JS, não utilizar `var`, mas sim `let` ou `const`.